# Is there a way to normalise the bodyFilename generated for recorded stubs?

Tags: wiremock

When recording a session with wiremock-standalone, I get the mapping file generated `foo-bar-RLCTY.json` which includes a link to the body with the same discriminator.

```
"response" : {
    "status" : 200,
    "bodyFileName" : "foo-bar-RLCTY.json"
}
```

Is there a way to control (seed) the naming of the discriminator, so that I can get the recording to generate the same stub name on each recording session?

It would make my git history a lot less messy!

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](http://wiremock.org/docs/record-playback/) This is not possible.

Comment: Can you quote that please? Naturally I read the docs before posting. Sure it's not mentioned explicitly, but I was hoping it was an undocumented feature. Guess I could just add the feature myself :)